# Figure Placement in twocolumn mode

Tags: floats, two-column

I have unable to fit the `figures` are in `2nd Page`. It's printing in `3rd Page` onwards. How to get the `figure` should align in `top of the 2nd page`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn{\title{Article Title Here}
\author{balaji}
\maketitle
\twocolumn[]\begin{figure*}
\centering\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}
\end{figure*}

\begin{table*}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\        4 & 5 & 6 \\        7 & 8 & 9
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blabla}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}


\lipsum[1-5] 


\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want standard twocolumn (`[twocolumn]` and `\twocolumn`) or `multicols` balanced columns which should use a `multicols` environment. Your example uses standard markup but loads multicols (which doesn't really work and produces the warning `Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the markup that was causing warnings in the log, and the floats appear at the top of page 2 as you requested:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Article Title Here}
\author{balaji}
\maketitle
\begin{figure*}
\centering\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}
\end{figure*}

\begin{table*}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\        4 & 5 & 6 \\        7 & 8 & 9
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blabla}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}

% if you want to force both columns empty on the first page
\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak

\lipsum[1-5] 


\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And my `1st page` is `single column` and `2nd page` onwards is `twocolumn`. How do fix it?

Comment: Oh the title is in one col but the text started below it which is the default in article, I added some lines to force a break.

Comment: @In `article` class file it's working fine. But i have using `own` template and unable don't know how do fix it. Could you able to possible to fix in my `own` template. Can i post my template?

Comment: @Balaji try to make it as small as possible, delete everything you can while still showing the problem, then post it, it might be best to ask a new question as this question is generally useful for the standard classes but your setup might require special version.